# CMake trouble with Mingw

Tags: c++, sql, visual-c++, cmake, mingw

I want to build a C++ component using MinGW and CMake, but the provided documentation only lists an example for Visual Studio:

> ```
> C:\>MKDIR build
> C:\>cd build
> C:\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" -DWITH_BOOST=OFF -DWITH_ORACLE=OFF (...) ..\soci-X.Y.Z
> C:\build>msbuild.exe SOCI.sln
> ```

How do I build this for MinGW?

You will probably need the source of the example: http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/installation.html

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How to use the command or a link regarding the subject

Comment: What errors are you getting? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: This example needs VC++ in order to pull it off.  I only have Mingw

Comment: I don't have Windows so I can't answer for sure. But the `-G` option tells CMake what generator to use. Try changing it from `"Visual Studio 10"` to `"Unix Makefiles"`. You may also need to run `CMakeSetup` first and choose unix makefiles. But try changing the `-G` first and see if that does it. Search around for `cmake generator mingw` and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you link me to the gui version?

Comment: it's named `cmake-gui.exe` and it should reside in the same /bin directory as cmake.exe. When you click the config button it should ask you to choose what compiler toolchain to use.

Comment: Instead of "Visual Studio 10" or "Unix Makefiles" try "MinGW Makefiles". For a complete list of all possible generators, simply type cmake --help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
C:\>MKDIR build
C:\>cd build
C:\build>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DWITH_BOOST=OFF -DWITH_ORACLE=OFF (...) ..\soci-X.Y.Z
C:\build>make
```

You'll need MinGW installed and available in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Hello! What version of mingw did you use? I am trying to compile it with no success.